# How to fetch hard drive details (serial number, manufacturer) programmatically in QNX?

Tags: hard-drive, qnx

fHow to fetch hard drive details (serial number, manufacturer) programmatically QNX linux.
Can I read it directly from filesystem ? or what are the other way of fetching hard disk details ?

Tried following:

```
if((fd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error with open() on %s.  Make sure it exists.\n", argv[1]);
  perror (open );
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


error = devctl(fd, DCMD_CAM_DEV_SERIAL_NUMBER, buf, len, NULL);
```

As a result i am getting only:
2GB NANDrive 300003

How to fetch manufacturer and other info like type/model/path on filesystem etc.

Comment: _"...programmatically QNX linux"_ - QNX isn't Linux - they're completely separate operating systems...

Comment: _"Tried many ways to fetch but could not get."_ - Please tell us at least one of the approaches that you've tried, otherwise we're less-inclined to believe you.